# Negative z-index of an element that has a positive z-index

Tags: css, z-index

I have the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  #nav {
    color:white;
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    height:30px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background:blue;

  }
  #controls {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-10;
    top:30px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:red;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
  <div id="nav">
    <span>Icon</span>
    <div id="controls">Hidden Controls</div>
  </div>
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `#controls` is visible because the parent element has a z-index greater than the `#content`.  Is there a way to set the `#controls` to have a z-index less than the `#content` such that it is invisible?

Comment: What is the behavior that you're trying to achieve? Is `z-index` the only solution for you? Can you possibly hide/show `#controls` another way?

Comment: Since both elements are `position:fixed`, you don't have to nest them. It makes no difference because the top left positioning is refering to the window, not to the parent. Make them siblings instead of parent/child, and you can work with your `z-index`.